# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception Process.Start

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm working on a project that uses an api of a website to do stuff. It saves the data in a textfile and I want it to open the file at the end of the program. I use System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(myFile), but it throws an exception:

```
Unhandled exception. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (13): Permission denied
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.ForkAndExecProcess(String filename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean redirectStdin, Boolean redirectStdout, Boolean redirectStderr, Boolean setCredentials, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, UInt32[] groups, Int32& stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean usesTerminal, Boolean throwOnNoExec)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(String fileName)
   at ESEL_Scraper_2._0.Program.Main(String[] args) in /home/af2111/Schreibtisch/Coding/C#/ESEL Scraper 2.0/Program.cs:line 72
```

My code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
namespace ESEL_Scraper_2._0
{
    
    class MyJsonType
    {
        public string title { get; set; }

        public string tags {get; set;}

        public string category {get; set;}

        public string location {get; set;}

        public int id { get; set; }

        public string startdatetime {get; set;}

    }
    class Root { public MyJsonType[] termine { get; set; } }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int queryResults = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("How many days do you want to go back?");
            String userInput = Console.ReadLine();
            int result = Int32.Parse(userInput);
            Console.WriteLine("What do you want to search for?");
            String userInput2 = Console.ReadLine();
            Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopWatch.Start();
            for(int j = 0; j < result; j++) {
            DateTime somePreviousDay = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-j);
            String somePreviousDayString = somePreviousDay.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
            Console.WriteLine(somePreviousDayString);
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            string site = client.DownloadString($"https://esel.at/api/termine/data?date={somePreviousDayString}&selection=false");
            var myJsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(site);
            for(int i = 0; i < myJsonObject.termine.Length; i++) {
                if(myJsonObject.termine[i].tags.Contains(userInput2) || myJsonObject.termine[i].title.Contains(userInput2) || myJsonObject.termine[i].category.Contains(userInput2)){
                    using (System.IO.StreamWriter file =
                   new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"eselData.txt", true))
                    {
                    file.WriteLine($"Titel: {myJsonObject.termine[i].title}; Tags: {myJsonObject.termine[i].tags}; Datum und Zeit: {myJsonObject.termine[i].startdatetime}; Location: {myJsonObject.termine[i].location}; Kategorie: {myJsonObject.termine[i].category}");
                    }
                    queryResults++;
                }
                
            }
            }
            stopWatch.Stop();
            TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
            string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
            ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
            ts.Milliseconds / 10);     
            Console.WriteLine($"Time taken: " + elapsedTime); 
            Console.WriteLine($"Found tags: " + queryResults); 
            
            if(queryResults > 0) {
               using (System.IO.StreamWriter file =
                   new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"eselStats.txt", true))
                    {
                    file.WriteLine($"{userInput2}: {queryResults} Ergebnisse.");
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("eselData.txt");
                    }    
            }


        }
    }
}
```

My File does get created and it seems like there shouldn't be a problem.
Does someone know how to fix it?

Comment: `Access Denied` if the path is correct, then you probably don't have permission on this path, for testing, rerun Visual Studio in Administrator mode and check it again.

Comment: I use vs code on linux, shall I just do sudo dotnet run?

Answer (score 3):

Linux systems show `Permission denied` when you try to execute a file which is not executable. I don't think that you want to execute the text file. You rather want to open it with the default text editor.

I'm not sure whether this works on all Linux systems but at least on Windows you achieve this by setting `ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute` to `true`. It is disabled in .NET Core by default. See Microsoft's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute?view=netcore-3.1#System_Diagnostics_ProcessStartInfo_UseShellExecute).

Example code:

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("eselData.txt")
{
    UseShellExecute = true
};
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: @af2111 Can you mark this answer as solution if it works for you?